# Add Underline To <img> tag inside <a> tag

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have an `<a>` tag that has both text and an image inside. I want the image and text to be underlined as shown below:

[image]

what I keep getting is this though:

[image]

As you can see the underline does not extend under the arrow. Here is my code:

```
  <a target="_blank" href="http://url.com" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#000001;" >Call To Action <img src="image/path/triangle.png" border="0" /></a>
```

Now I can't put a border-bottom on the wrapping container because on mobile I need the text to be underlined and this would only put a border on the bottom of the text.

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in a div and put a bottom border on that.  Just don't do anything else style-wise to the div, and it won't interfere with anything else.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a closing `a` tag.

Comment: @Yass Thanks I fixed it.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I can't do that because of the reason I stated above. Doesn't work on mobile.

Comment: @DigitalMC see my answer, nothing wrapping, just using `a`

Comment: Why use an image to display the ▶ symbol?

Comment: @John Slegers I was worried about email client compatibility. What is code for that?

Comment: @DigitalMC : I'm not entirely certain if it's supported by HTML mails or not, but you could always try. The HTML entity for the symbol is `&#9654;` or `&#x25b6;` -> http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25B6/index.htm

Comment: @John Slegers it works 99% of the time, but apple changes it to one of their Emojiis ... ugg. There are hackrounds but I think i may stick to image for now. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to style `a` with `border-bottom` and remove the `text-decoration:underline`

```html
<a target="_blank" href="http://url.com" style="border-bottom:1px solid red;text-decoration:none;color:#000001;">Call To Action <img src="//lorempixel.com/20/20" border="0" /></a>
```

Comment: Works pretty well so far! Let me do some render tests and confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose both tags within a

```
    <span style="text-decoration:underline">
```

tag.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work for me, does it work for you? Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlink tag doesn't have a close tag `</a>`, if you want to close it make it like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://url.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #000001;">
  Call To Action <img src="image/path/triangle.png" border="0" />
</a>
```

Reference:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html
- https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/a

Also, I recommend you separate design from content.

Comment: Yeah that was just a typo, my bad. Thanks.